# How to feather the text reveal effect

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am rendering text using freetype.

Rendering is done in the typical style of drawing a rectangle and mapping the image of the text on it.

[image]

i want to reveal the above text based on a variable "effectAlphaValue"

if the value for "effectAlphaValue" is 100 than whole of the text should be visible.

when the value of "effectAlphaValue" is 55 than this is how the text should look.

[image]

i have been able to attain this effect.

The issue is that i am not able to add  feather this effect as shown in the image below.

Here "effectAlphaValue" is 55  but it is feathered.
[image]

This is the code where i am revealing the text rectangles individually based on the effectAlphaValue.

i would be greatfull if someone can guide me or show me pseudo code to how to implement the feather effect.

```
int currentCharNumber = 1;
int eachCharValue = 100 / totalNumberOfChars;  // what should be the value of each char for alpha opacity(spaces not included)
for (c = str.begin(); c != str.end(); c++)
        {
            Character ch = Characters[*c]; // get the char from the character map
            // Calculate the xPos and the yPos for the rectangle vbo here
            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // Update VBO for each character
            GLfloat vertices[6][5] = {

                { xpos ,     ypos - h , 0.0 ,     0.0, 1.0 },
                { xpos + w , ypos ,     0.0 ,     1.0, 0.0 },
                { xpos ,     ypos,     0.0 ,    0.0, 0.0 },

                { xpos ,     ypos - h , 0.0,      0.0, 1.0 },
                { xpos + w , ypos - h , 0.0,      1.0, 1.0 },
                { xpos + w , ypos ,     0.0,       1.0, 0.0 }
            };

            // Render glyph texture over quad
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ch.TextureID);
            // Update content of VBO memory
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->VBO);
            glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(vertices), vertices);
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
            //============UPDate the alpha value for current char=======================

            if (*c != ' ') // only calculate alpha for non spaces
            {
                int startValue = (currentCharNumber - 1) * eachCharValue; // 
                int currentValue = effectAlphaValue - startValue;   
                float finalOpacity;
                float percentValueCurrent = ((float)currentValue  / (float)eachCharValue) * 100;                
                finalOpacity = ((float)percentValueCurrent / 100.0f);   
                finalOpacity = ceil(finalOpacity);
                lastAlphaValue = finalOpacity;              
                if (finalOpacity > 100.0)
                    finalOpacity = 100.0;

                ShaderManager::GetShader("TextShader").SetFloat("opacity", finalOpacity / 100.0f);  // set the current opacity
                currentCharNumber++;
            }
            // Render quad
            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
            // Now advance cursors for next glyph
            x += (ch.Advance >> 6); // Bitshift by 6 to get value in pixels (1/64th times 2^6 = 64)
            x += this->Kerning;             
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: @Rabbid76  Thank you , yes this is giving the feather effect but how can i increase or decrease the effect ?

Comment: if the feather effect is 0 than no feather should happen.

Comment: @Rabbid76  Aplogies for missing out the point that i would have another variable named effectAlphaRange which would be used to feather.

Comment: if the variable  would be 0 than no feather will happen .

Comment: your this formulae was working fine but there was no feather control.

Comment: finalOpacity = effectAlphaValue + (100 - effectAlphaValue) * (float)(totalNumberOfChars - currentCharNumber) / (float)totalNumberOfChars;

Comment: effectAlphaValue  is to reveal the text at 0 no text visible and at 100 all of it visible.

Comment: feather  effect would be from another variable  which will control how much feather needs to be done.